# JavaScript Recursion: Get the length of an array using recursion without accessing its length property

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion, return

Get the length of an array using recursion without accessing its length property.

My Code Below:

```
function getLength(array, count=0) {

  if (array.length === 0){
    return 0
  }

  else {
    count ++; 

    array.pop()
    return getLength(array, count)
  }
  return count; 
}

// To check if you've completed the challenge, uncomment these console.logs!
console.log(getLength([1])); // -> 1
console.log(getLength([1, 2])); // -> 2
console.log(getLength([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // -> 5
console.log(getLength([], 0)); // -> 0
```

When I run my code on the third console.log:

```
console.log(getLength([1, 2]));
```

it returns 0 instead of 2

What am I doing wrong?

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

figured it out:

```
function getLength(array, count=0) {

  if (array.length === 0){
    return count
  }

  else {
    count ++; 

    array.pop()
    return getLength(array, count)
  } 
}
```

Comment: really a dupe??

Comment: Cause you `return 0`.

Comment: @ninaScholz no, I'm not sure wether the OP uses us to solve code challenges. Thats up to a debate.

Comment: @PineNuts0, you still use `length`.

Comment: Feel free to self answer then :)

Comment: @Jonas:  I'm self studying JavaScript and go through practice problems.  If I get stuck, I first look for solutions online, on Repl, etc.  If I still don't understand then I post here; is that not allowed?

Comment: For sure that is allowed and appreciated, thats what SO is for :) It's just that you asked two questions shortly after another, so it looked as if you were rushing through assignments ... I closed the question temporarily to figure that out, ...

Comment: Got it, trust me ... I do a lot of googling before I ask;  And I am not in school

Comment: Sure, nevermind. Now it's time to clean up things: Answer your own question (why didn't it work, what solved it) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the item at index zero exists. This works only for non sparse arrays.

```js
function getLength(array) {
    return 0 in array ? 1 + getLength(array.slice(1)) : 0;
}

console.log(getLength([1]));             // 1
console.log(getLength([1, 2]));          // 2
console.log(getLength([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // 5
console.log(getLength([], 0));           // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution (which also does not work on sparse arrays) is

```
const len1 = arr => arr.reduce(n => n + 1, 0)
```

And a related, but less simple, one does work on sparse arrays:

```
const len2 = (arr) => Array.from(arr, _ => 1).reduce(n => n + 1, 0)
```